# How to set max width as a percentage or static value

Tags: tailwind-css

For width on an element with tailwind you can set it by a percentage or fixed rem value.  For setting max-width you can only set it to the size of a breakpoint.

Why is this?

Is there any way to set max-width to a percentage or a fixed size that isn't a breakpoint?

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any way to set max-width to a percentage or a fixed size that
> isn't a breakpoint?

You need [customize tailwind.config.js](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-width#customizing)

```
  // tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    theme: {
      maxWidth: {
+       '1/4': '25%',
+       '1/2': '300px',
+       '3/4': '75%',
      }
    }
  }
```

So, you got fixed max width to a percentage or px.

[image]

> Why is this?

You are not limited in settings and capabilities, on the contrary, the Tailwind CSS provides you with a standard that has proven itself in practice.

But if you need fine tuning for your project, you can always do it.

Enjoy using Tailwind CSS!

Answer (score 8):

the answer of Dmitry is correct, but beware:

If you do it like he mentioned, none of the `maxWidth` values will work, except the values in the configuration.
If you want to just extend the base `maxWidth` values (provided by tailwind), you have to put the configuration inside the `extend` section like so:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      maxWidth: {
        '1/4': '25%',
        '1/2': '300px',
        '3/4': '75%',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great clarification! Spend some time with this issue.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, in your theme as described in the answers above.

BUT, from the v3 [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-width#using-custom-values), "…If you need to use a one-off max-width value that doesn’t make sense to include in your theme, use square brackets to generate a property on the fly using any arbitrary value…"

```
<div class="max-w-[50%]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set percentage values like this in `tailwind.config.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      maxWidth: {
        50: '50%',
        60: '60%',
        70: '70%',
        80: '80%',
        90: '90%',
        // 100% is not required as max-w-full will be present by default
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in the mark up you can use it this way

```html
   <div className="max-w-90">
      View Product
   </div>
```

**Note**: If it doesn't work, make sure you restart the local server, `yarn dev`